# disabled processes in android

Tags: android, linux, process, linux-kernel

I have rooted android phone,and i wrote an app which is installed on my phone as a system app. i want to find out how can i **enable my app** **programatically**, when it is disabled by user or another app.

where can i find disabled apps in android? i mean, running processes can be seen in /proc , but where are disabled processes when disabled by the application manager?

is there any way to enable one app  via another app programatically?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled packages list is stored in `/data/system/users/<user_id>/package-restrictions.xml`. 0 is id of default user. App state can be modified by [PackageManagerService.setComponentEnabledSetting()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#PackageManagerService.setComponentEnabledSetting%28android.content.ComponentName%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29) or by shell command `pm enable` / `pm disable`. To get list of disabled packages: `pm list packages -d`.

Comment: is there any way to prevent user from disabling my app from application manager, programatically? for example disable the "Disable" button in application manager?

Comment: i see some apps which their "Disable" button is inactive(grayed)

Comment: System (signed using system key) and home (launcher) packages are not disablable: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/5.1.1_r1/com/android/settings/applications/InstalledAppDetails.java#InstalledAppDetails.handleDisableable%28android.widget.Button%29